# IndexError: list index out of range when adding a new column to a data set on Shapelets-platform query

Tags: python, time-series

I'm trying to add a new column to a data set using the `add_column` method, but I'm getting an `IndexError: list index out of range` error.
Here is the data I am using:

|  | Weight | Width | Lenght | Color_Categories | Material | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 3 | 8 | Red | Cotton | 7 |
| 1 | 15 | 5 | 12 | Blue | Polyester | 9 |
| 2 | 12 | 4 | 10 | Green | Silk | 4 |
| 3 | 8 | 6 | 6 | Yellow | Wool | 12 |
| 4 | 11 | 3 | 9 | Purple | Linen | 5 |

and here is the code:

```
import shapelets as sh
from shapelets.functions import avg

session = sh.sandbox()
data = session.from_csv("/root/data.csv")

data.add_column("avg_tot", lambda row: (row.Width*row.Lenght)/avg(row.age))
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: It is better to show your `data.py` file (full or simplified) in your question.

Comment: I just updated my question with the data. I am trying to determine the average growth of a plant depending on its age. since my dataset is too big, I can only show you the head()

Comment: By the way you have a typo in `row.Lenght`. Shouldn't it be `row.Length`?

Comment: yes, I just saw that I made a mistake when adding my data for the previous comments

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was happening to you. when I tried your code, I had an issue working with the avg() function. If you are trying to get the average of the total age, I would recommend you to do the average group by the material.

such as:

```
import shapelets as sh   

session = sh.sandbox()
data = session.from_csv("/root/data.csv")   
                                                         
average = session.from_sql(f'select avg({data.age}) from {data} group by {data.material}')
data.add_column("avg_tot", lambda row: (row.Width*row.Lenght)/average)
```

With this, you will have a better grasp of the material growth.

you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo
I hope this help you